# PDO in PHP - What parameters can I bind outside of the query or not

Tags: php, pdo

I'm curious why this code works fine:

```
function updateRecord($idFieldName, $recordID, $fieldName, $recordValue){
            $dbConnection=$this->dbConnect();
            $updated=false;
            while (!$updated){
                $query=$dbConnection->prepare("UPDATE $this->table SET $fieldName = :recordValue WHERE $idFieldName = :recordID");
                $query->bindParam(":recordValue", $recordValue);
                $query->bindParam(":recordID", $recordID);
                $updated=$query->execute();
            }
        }
```

Whereas this one doesn't:

```
function updateRecord($idFieldName, $recordID, $fieldName, $recordValue){
            $dbConnection=$this->dbConnect();
            $updated=false;
            while (!$updated){
                $query=$dbConnection->prepare("UPDATE $this->table SET :fieldName = :recordValue WHERE $idFieldName = :recordID");
                $query->bindParam(":fieldName", $fieldName);
                $query->bindParam(":recordValue", $recordValue);
                $query->bindParam(":recordID", $recordID);
                $updated=$query->execute();
            }
        }
```

I don't understand what parameters can be bound outside the query statement, and which ones have to be included directly into the statement.

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen? At which point does which code fail how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table name as parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [can't use dynamic column names as data parameters in PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter) (nor in any other PHP SQL library AFAIK).

You'll have to insert the column name directly into the string. To avoid SQL injection, you should compare the column name against a list of existing valid column names.

Comment: In my case, `$fieldName` is not a user input, it comes from my code.  I suppose that in this case, I don't need the switch statement.  I suppose there could be something to be gained by centralizing the values this can take, but it would come at the expense of readability.